# jQuery .delegate() with a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jkey

I am using a plugin named : [jkey](http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey/).

Now i want to use the .deligate() with it.

The basic syntax of this plugin is :

```
$(document).jkey('a',function(){
    jkey.log('You pressed the a key.');
});
```

**QUESTION**
How do i supply the arguments like in this i want to send the key value 'a' i tried to do this

```
$("#hmm").delegate(".mm","jkey","a",function() {
    $("#get").html("WOW");
});
```

but failed

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: @evan As the #hmm is not present at the start i need to add delegate to it to add event listners on it. But i want an plugin event listner to work. For that i want to pass a value. How do i pass that value ?

Comment: My plugin, unfortunately doesn't create a new event so I don't believe delegate would work. Could you add this as a feature request to the bug tracker to allow async calls of jKey? I believe Amin below has the right concept.

Comment: But the code amin gave doesnt works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#hmm` needs to be present at the start and `.mm` is what is being bound. You also need to give it an event for example `'click'`

```
$("#hmm").delegate(".mm","click",function() {
    $(this).jkey('a',function(){
        jkey.log('You pressed the a key.');
    });
});
```

The code above doesn't make much sense but it will listen for a click on an element with class of "mm" inside an existing element with an id of "hmm". Once click, it'll bind jkey to the .mm element.

Elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do and I can give a better example

Comment: You should add a data to ".mm" so that you can check if it exists and not rebind jkey each time, something like `if (!$(this).data("initialized")) $(this).data("initialized", true); /* bind jkey */ `

Comment: I'd suggest this. You can also look for a "focus" instead of click so when people tag through. I'm assuming you are trying to capture a input field's key presses, right?

Comment: Yea i also think that focus would be better. U can take an example of appending input boxes to a div

Comment: @kritya - you'll have to elaborate on what type of event you want to bind on. Edit your question and explain what it is you're trying to do. The code above binds jkey dynamically on click of .mm.

Comment: @amin i am soo fool. That did worked. I just went a little wrong. :(
Sorry and Thanks :D