# The plugin does not work with dynamically updated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Shortcuts to description for plugin: http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jqBarGraph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="button" style="width: 100px; height: 40px; background-color: red;">button</div>
  <div id="multiGraph"></div>
  <script>
    graphResolutionByYear = new Array([
      [5, 11, 6, 11], "1"
    ]);
    $("#multiGraph").jqBarGraph({
   data: graphResolutionByYear,
   
   width: 850, 
height: 250
  
});


    $('#button').click(function() {

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "d.php",
            data: {
              date: "15"
            },
            success: function(msg) { 
             alert (msg)
    var qqq = msg;
              graphResolutionByYear = new Array([
                [qqq, qqq, qqq, qqq], "1"
              ]);
              $('#multiGraph').jqBarGraph({
               
      data: graphResolutionByYear,
               width: 850, 
               height: 250
             
    });


           }
  });
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

file d.php:`<?
echo $_POST['date'];
?>`

After downloading the page plugin works normally, but if I put in an array of data from AJAX-request, the graphics are not built.

Comment: maybe this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017852/jquery-delegate-with-a-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the final button click event.

```js
graphResolutionByYear = new Array([
  [5, 11, 6, 11], "1"
]);
$('#graph').jqBarGraph({
  data: graphResolutionByYear
});


$('#button').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "date.php",
    data: {
      date: "01.01.2015"
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      var qqq = msg;
      graphResolutionByYear = new Array([
        [qqq, qqq, qqq, qqq], "1"
      ]);
      $('#graph').jqBarGraph({
        data: graphResolutionByYear
      });


    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
 * jqBarGraph - jQuery plugin
 * @version: 1.1 (2011/04/03)
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.2 or later 
 * @author Ivan Lazarevic
 * Examples and documentation at: http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/
 * 
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * 
 */

(function($){var opts=new Array;var level=new Array;$.fn.jqBarGraph=$.fn.jqbargraph=function(options){init=function(el){opts[el.id]=$.extend({},$.fn.jqBarGraph.defaults,options);$(el).css({'width':opts[el.id].width,'height':opts[el.id].height,'position':'relative','text-align':'center'});doGraph(el);};sum=function(ar){total=0;for(val in ar){total+=ar[val];}
return total.toFixed(2);};max=function(ar){maxvalue=0;for(var val in ar){value=ar[val][0];if(value instanceof Array)value=sum(value);if(parseFloat(value)>parseFloat(maxvalue))maxvalue=value;}
return maxvalue;};maxMulti=function(ar){maxvalue=0;maxvalue2=0;for(var val in ar){ar2=ar[val][0];for(var val2 in ar2){if(ar2[val2]>maxvalue2)maxvalue2=ar2[val2];}
if(maxvalue2>maxvalue)maxvalue=maxvalue2;}
return maxvalue;};doGraph=function(el){arr=opts[el.id];data=arr.data;if(data==undefined){$(el).html('There is not enought data for graph');return;}
if(arr.sort=='asc')data.sort(sortNumberAsc);if(arr.sort=='desc')data.sort(sortNumberDesc);legend='';prefix=arr.prefix;postfix=arr.postfix;space=arr.barSpace;legendWidth=arr.legend?arr.legendWidth:0;fieldWidth=($(el).width()-legendWidth)/data.length;totalHeight=$(el).height();var leg=new Array();max=max(data);colPosition=0;for(var val in data){valueData=data[val][0];if(valueData instanceof Array)
value=sum(valueData);else
value=valueData;lbl=data[val][1];color=data[val][2];unique=val+el.id;if(color==undefined&&arr.colors==false)
color=arr.color;if(arr.colors&&!color){colorsCounter=arr.colors.length;if(colorsCounter==colPosition)colPosition=0;color=arr.colors[colPosition];colPosition++;}
if(arr.type=='multi')color='none';if(lbl==undefined)lbl=arr.lbl;out="<div class='graphField"+el.id+"' id='graphField"+unique+"' style='position: absolute'>";out+="<div class='graphValue"+el.id+"' id='graphValue"+unique+"'>"+prefix+value+postfix+"</div>";out+="<div class='graphBar"+el.id+"' id='graphFieldBar"+unique+"' style='background-color:"+color+";position: relative; overflow: hidden;'></div>";if(!arr.legend||arr.legends)
out+="<div class='graphLabel"+el.id+"' id='graphLabel"+unique+"'>"+lbl+"</div>";out+="</div>";$(el).append(out);totalHeightBar=totalHeight-$('.graphLabel'+el.id).height()-$('.graphValue'+el.id).height();fieldHeight=(totalHeightBar*value)/max;$('#graphField'+unique).css({'left':(fieldWidth)*val,'width':fieldWidth-space,'margin-left':space});if(valueData instanceof Array){if(arr.type=="multi"){maxe=maxMulti(data);totalHeightBar=fieldHeight=totalHeight-$('.graphLabel'+el.id).height();$('.graphValue'+el.id).remove();}else{maxe=max;}
for(i in valueData){heig=totalHeightBar*valueData[i]/maxe;wid=parseInt((fieldWidth-space)/valueData.length);sv='';fs=0;if(arr.showValues){sv=arr.prefix+valueData[i]+arr.postfix;fs=12;}
o="<div class='subBars"+el.id+"' style='height:"+heig+"px; background-color: "+arr.colors[i]+"; left:"+wid*i+"px; color:"+arr.showValuesColor+"; font-size:"+fs+"px' >"+sv+"</div>";$('#graphFieldBar'+unique).prepend(o);}}
if(arr.type=='multi')
$('.subBars'+el.id).css({'width':wid,'position':'absolute','bottom':0});if(arr.position=='bottom')$('.graphField'+el.id).css('bottom',0);if(!arr.legends)
leg.push([color,lbl,el.id,unique]);if(arr.animate){$('#graphFieldBar'+unique).css({'height':0});$('#graphFieldBar'+unique).animate({'height':fieldHeight},arr.speed*1000);}else{$('#graphFieldBar'+unique).css({'height':fieldHeight});}}
for(var l in arr.legends){leg.push([arr.colors[l],arr.legends[l],el.id,l]);}
createLegend(leg);if(arr.legend){$(el).append("<div id='legendHolder"+unique+"'></div>");$('#legendHolder'+unique).css({'width':legendWidth,'float':'right','text-align':'left'});$('#legendHolder'+unique).append(legend);$('.legendBar'+el.id).css({'float':'left','margin':3,'height':12,'width':20,'font-size':0});}
if(arr.title){$(el).wrap("<div id='graphHolder"+unique+"'></div>");$('#graphHolder'+unique).prepend(arr.title).css({'width':arr.width+'px','text-align':'center'});}};createLegend=function(legendArr){legend='';for(var val in legendArr){legend+="<div id='legend"+legendArr[val][3]+"' style='overflow: hidden; zoom: 1;'>";legend+="<div class='legendBar"+legendArr[val][2]+"' id='legendColor"+legendArr[val][3]+"' style='background-color:"+legendArr[val][0]+"'></div>";legend+="<div class='legendLabel"+legendArr[val][2]+"' id='graphLabel"+unique+"'>"+legendArr[val][1]+"</div>";legend+="</div>";}};this.each(function()
{init(this);})};$.fn.jqBarGraph.defaults={barSpace:10,width:400,height:300,color:'#000000',colors:false,lbl:'',sort:false,position:'bottom',prefix:'',postfix:'',animate:true,speed:1.5,legendWidth:100,legend:false,legends:false,type:false,showValues:true,showValuesColor:'#fff',title:false};function sortNumberAsc(a,b){if(a[0]<b[0])return-1;if(a[0]>b[0])return 1;return 0;}
function sortNumberDesc(a,b){if(a[0]>b[0])return-1;if(a[0]<b[0])return 1;return 0;}})(jQuery);
  </script>
<div id="button"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
```